# Wso2is SCIM support

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I'm evaluating wso2is as a SCIM Service Provider.

If I try to create a new user with an address I get a 400 error with the message "Request is unparseable, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema".

Curl command used is:

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"gunasinghe","givenName":"hasinitg"},"userName":"hasinitg3@test.com","password":"hasinitg","addresses":[{"formatted":"100 Universal floor 2","streetAddress":"100 Universal Address","type":"work","primary":true,"locality":"Hollywood","region":"CA","country":"USA","postalCode":"91608"}]}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users
```

If I remove the "addresses" property from the code above, then the user is successfully created.

Does wso2is support [SCIM specification](http://www.simplecloud.info/specs/draft-scim-core-schema-00.html) addresses? I'm using wso2is 4.6.0.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

{"formatted":"100_Universal_floor_2","streetAddress":"100_Universal Address","type":"work","primary":true,"locality":"Hollywood","region":"CA","country":"USA","postalCode":"91608"}

Can you please try this, just replace spaces with _

This will avoid your error but still addresses are not stored.